# MySQL: How to return empty record when all fields are NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql, null

Situation 1:

```
SELECT SUM(mark) AS totalMark, userID, credit
FROM users, marks
WHERE marks.receiverID = users.userID
AND userID = '2'
```

It will return

```
totalMark   userID  credit
---------------------------
0           2       0.0
```

And it is very good, no problem. But here is the situation 2:

```
SELECT SUM(mark) AS totalMark, userID, credit
FROM users, marks
WHERE marks.receiverID = users.userID
AND userID = '-1'
```

Result:

```
totalMark   userID  credit
---------------------------
NULL        NULL    NULL
```

But what I want is return nothing (no record found). Anyone could help me?

Comment: Anytime you use an aggregate you will get at least one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an aggregate function like SUM(), the query is bound to return a row.  But since it's summing no values, the result of the sum is undefined.

You could work around this in the following way:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT SUM(mark) AS totalMark, userID, credit
    FROM users, marks
    WHERE marks.receiverID = users.userID
    AND userID = '-1'
) t
WHERE t.totalMark IS NOT NULL;
```